# Is it safe to make assumptions about the packing of two consectutive pointers in a C struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, packing

I'm working on language bindings from GObject based libraries to Standard ML. More precisely I'm implementing support for the G(S)List collection type. This implementation requires extracting data from G(S)Lists links and getting the next link from within Standard ML. Rather that calling one of the G(S)List functions through the FFI, I was hoping that it would be possible to use the FFI's pointer manipulation functions to access the appropriate struct elements for efficiency. However, this requires that it's possible to predict the offset of the second, next link, pointer in the struct. For reference, this is what the [GSList](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html) link struct looks like

```
struct GSList {
    gpointer data;
    GSList *next;
};
```

which I think is no surprise to anyone. It's safe to assume that the pointer to a struct points to it's first element, ie the data pointer, but how about the second element? Can I make any platform independent assumptions about the offset of the second element in relation to the first?

Comment: If `gpointer` is just a `typedef` to a pointer type, then it's *likely* that there will be no padding, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's safe to assume that the pointer to a struct points to it's first
>   element, ie the data pointer, but how about the second element?

Yes. This is safe. The address of a `struct` object and the address of its first element are guaranteed to be the same. No padding is allowed *before* the first member of a struct.

> Can I make any platform independent assumptions about the offset of
>   the second element in relation to the first?

No. This is not safe. There may be padding bytes between first and second element of the structure and any assumptions is non-portable. But you can use
[`offsetof`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html) to get the offset of *any* member from the start of the structure.

For example, you can the offset of `next` with:

```
size_t next_offset =  offsetof(struct GSList, next);
```

GCC provides an [attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html) to disable the padding:

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

And similar option is provided by MSVC too.

Comment: The first statement is correct as long as the first member is not a bitfield `;-)`

Comment: I think `offsetof` could come in handy. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general, you cannot make such an assumption.  There might be specific alignment requirements for the second member of your structure that will cause padding bytes to be inserted in the structure layout.

There is a special case: if second member has the same type as the first, it seems reasonable to assume that there be no such padding, but the Standard leaves extra flexibility for the compiler, so there is no guarantee.

This special case does not apply here anyway since `gpointer` is probably a typedef for a `void *` pointer. On some architectures (rare and disappearing, but Cray used to have one), pointers to different types may have a different representation and thus different alignment requirements.

Comment: Yes, `gpointer` is indeed typedef for `void*`. I guess it's better to call the `g_slist_nth` function or, even better, write a wrapper C function for the `g_slist_next` macro, because it's not possible to use macros through the Standard ML FFIs.

Comment: It is indeed debatable whether the `next` pointer should come first in this structure... It would allow for generic lists.

Comment: "... it seems reasonable to assume that there be no such padding" No, it is not safe. It is very well possible the compiler adds padding to e.g. cache-lines or other memory alignment optimisations (at the cost of wasting memory, of course).

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, the standard even requires a `struct` to have no padding before the first member.

For other members, it is not safe. You can, however, use [`offsetof`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3) to get the offset.

Actually, the Linux Kernel uses the [`container_of`](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) macro to get the base-address of a structure from the address of one of its members. Note this does not use other functions of the kernel, so it can be used as-is in your code, too.:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})

struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int *ip;  // assume points to the `b` member in an object of struct S

// get address of the struct S
struct S *sp = container_of(ip, struct S, b);
```

As defined, it uses gcc extensions to add some type-safety (see the link). One might be able to adopt to a different toolchain by removing the safety-measures.